# Unable to run async functions after migrating from WSGI to ASGI in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-channels, asgi

- While implementing channels feature in DRF I migrated from `WSGI` to `ASGI`.
- So currently I have REST API and channels in same project->same app.
- Channels are working and existing APIs as well **except ones with `async def` in it**

Im getting error below -

```
RuntimeError: You cannot use AsyncToSync in the same thread as an async event loop - just await the async function directly.
```

Since this method is called in a `view` which not `async` I cannot `await` while calling function. Im assuming the `WSGI->ASGI` migration is cause of this break.

HELP PLEASE!!

Comment: I couldn't find ideal solution yet. For now, I ended up creating 2 apps - 1 for  REST (WSGI/gunicorn) and 2nd for channel (ASGI/daphne).